# How to create an array from selected csv values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
array = []

for vid in account:
    vid_shares = (df.loc[df['account'] == '123', 'shares'])
    array.append(vid_shares)

print(array)
```

This produces something in the following format.

```
1      10.0
2      15.0
3       0.0
4      12.0
5      17.0
6       0.0
7       9.0
8      12.0
9      13.0
10      8.0
11     30.0
12      0.0
13     16.0
Name: shares, dtype: float64]
```

How would I convert this into `[10, 15, 0, 12]` etc so that I can use the sum function to output all the values added together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the sum.

```
total = df["shares"].sum()
```

If you want a list.

```
shares = df["shares"].tolist()
```

If you want an array.

```
arr = df["shares"].to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum of all the values is calculated with `array.sum()`
e.g. in your case :

```
>>> array.sum()
142.0
```